# Assign jsp List of objects to javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, jsp

I have one List in JSP named cumulatorList which is list of Objects. The Object of class has few String and Date variables as its attributes.

I have to transfer this list from jsp to javascript .
I am using the following code:

### code

```
var cumList = new Array();
<%! 
int j = 0;
%>
for (int i = 0; i < <%=cumulatorList.size()%>;i++)
{
    <%
         session.setAttribute("cumListElement", cumulatorList.get(j++))
    %>
    cumList[i] = document.getElementById("cumListElement");
}

//Note: Here "cumListElement" is hidden element included in HTML.
```

But after adding the following code, my jsp page dissappears with no error. If I remove this part, everything works fine.

Please tell me how to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you generate a string with all the values in it?
I'm not a JSP expert but you should be able to loop and yield each value

```
var cumlist = [ 
<%
  // Loop over JSP cumulatorList and return each of the values
%>
];

// Result: var cumlist = [ 'x', 'y', 'z' ];
```